# IE displaying form showing extra text

Tags: internet-explorer, webforms

I have a form on www.circlestarpetresort.com that shows correctly in everything except IE. IE has an extra "3 4" showing above the "check availabilty" submit button. I've looked all through the HTML and can not figure out where IE is getting the "3 4".

Comment: share some code please... use http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: You should run this through a validator, it won't even load in ie7 for me.

Answer (score 1):

These are the last two options in your Pets select box.
You should add a DocType to the beginning of your html such as:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

This should clear it up